# In ant design protable, is there a way to use a select in a search field, where all the options for the select are from an API call to remote server?

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
User {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    department: string;  
    status: number;
}
```

This is one record. The data columns are from API call. For search, I have input text for field "department". The requirement is to use a select for department from remote API call in search.

The department does not need to be show in the result table.

```
{
    title: 'department',
    dataIndex: 'department',
    hideInTable: true,
    hideInForm: true,
    hideInSearch: false,  
    valueType: 'select', 
}
```

I am not sure how to put the data to the select options. Has anyone tried this before?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think yes you can, all you need is to add valueEnum to the column props

```
{
    title: 'department',
    dataIndex: 'department',
    hideInTable: true,
    hideInForm: true,
    hideInSearch: false,  
    valueType: 'select', 
    valueEnum: {
    value:"label",
     
     }, 

}
```